# How to run dynamic query across multiple threads

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dynamic query to rebuild indexes and statistics on all of the linked servers attached to our central SQL Server and contained in the list. It works well, but runs the statements in series when they could complete much quicker if run on separate spids, since it is the remote servers that are doing the work.
Is there a way to alter the script to allow them to run in parallel, rather than wait for each to complete in turn?

```
WITH TillNames as (select * from (values 
('[DEVELOPERSVR]', '100', 'AD01'),
('[TESTSVR1]', '100', 'AD02'), 
('[TESTSVR2]', '100', 'AD03'), 
('[TESTSVR3]', '100', 'AD04')  -- and two hundred more.
) a ([TillName], [Branch], [TillDesc])) -- Branch and Till Desc used for other purposes, removed here
select * INTO #tills from TillNames 

declare @TillName as nvarchar(20), @Branch as nvarchar(5), @TillDesc as nvarchar(100) 
declare @sql as nvarchar(max)

declare mycursor cursor for Select [TillName], [Branch], [TillDesc] from #tills
declare @query as nvarchar(max)

open mycursor
fetch next from mycursor into @TillName, @Branch, @TillDesc
while @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
    set @sql = 'USE [LOCALDB]
                Declare     @TBname nvarchar(255), @SQL nvarchar(max) 
                select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''''BASE TABLE''''
                while @TBname is not null
                    BEGIN
                        begin try
                            set @SQL=''''ALTER INDEX ALL ON ['''' + @TBname + ''''] REBUILD; ''''
                            SET @SQL = @SQL + N''''UPDATE STATISTICS ['''' + @TBname + ''''] WITH FULLSCAN; ''''
                            EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @SQL
                        end try
                        begin catch
                        print ''''DID NOT WORK: '''' + @SQL
                        end catch
                        select @TBname = min(TABLE_NAME) from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_TYPE=''''BASE TABLE'''' and TABLE_NAME > @TBname          
                    END'
    set @query = N'EXEC (''' + @sql + N''') AT ' + @TillName
    exec (@query)
    fetch next from mycursor into @TillName, @Branch, @TillDesc
    END
close mycursor 
deallocate mycursor
drop table #tills
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest, albeit kludgey way I can think off is to create a Sql Server Agent job for each index rebuild, then fire off each job one-after-another.

*Hey, I said it was kludgey!* :)

The better way that involve a significant amount of code would be to use the Sql Server Service Broker. You can but together a basic framework pretty quickly but if you want it to be resilient then you'll want to spend some time on it.

Another method which may be something in between but involve writing code in a .Net language such as C#, would be to write a procedure that fires of asynchronous calls, although you might need to watch out for utilizing resources for that.

Your best 'external but internal' option would be to put the index rebuilds in an SSIS package and call that from your script, either as a Sql Agent job or called directly.,

***TL;DR***: Sql Server by itself does not offer any native method of running asynchronous queries via T-SQL.

Comment: Thanks, Rachel. Having each rebuild as a job is a last resort as we would need over 200.. but a single TSQL script could create 200 jobs on an immediate schedule that delete themselves on termination. Is this a way to get around running asynchronous queries?

Comment: Yes, it is and would require more permissions, buy yeah, that's a possibility. It all depends on how much code you're prepared to create! In addition you might not be able to delete a running job so you'd probably need to call a housekeeping 'fixed' job that'll check for completed 'temp' jobs and remove them.